# get the data from the datatable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

How to get the data object on click the cell.I have created the table and used datatable.I want to get the geography and customer type from the cell click I have tried as

```
$('#table tbody').on( 'click','td',  function () {
 //alert ('clicked');
   //var data1 = table.row().data();
   var data1 = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
   console.log(data1);
    alert( data1[0] +"'s Customer type: "+ data1[ 2 ] );
} );
```

my table id is table and I got the response as below in console for `console.log(data1);`

```
{Geography: "APAC", Current: "0", CustomerType: "AMRevenue", DSO: "0", OverDue: "0"}


getting undefined for data1[0] how to get the geo and customer type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a click event on `td` and click on each `td`, you can be able to get the value of that `td`'s data by using `$(this).text();`. Have a look at the snippet below and after running the snippet click on the `td` and see the value.

```js
$("#myTable tbody td").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Burl</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**`Update:`** If you click on a specific row and want to get the entire row's data you can simply follow this way:

```js
$("#myTable tbody td").click(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
    var cell1 = row.find("td:nth-child(1)").text(); // Find the first cell's data
    var cell2 = row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text(); // Find the second cell's data
    console.log(cell1 + " " + cell2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>Burl</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to assign *variable* as **table** for *datatable initialize* & in datatable there is one **initComplete** method so from this method to get table **id** by dynamically and then use click method functionality inside *initComplete* method as below code. So tr of tbody & get value **table.row(this).data()** method.
I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { title: "Geography" },
            { title: "Current" },
            { title: "Customer Type" },
            { title: "DSO" },
            { title: "OverDue" }
        ],
        initComplete: function(settings, json){
            $('#'+settings.sTableId+' tbody tr').on('click', function(){
                var data = table.row(this).data();
                console.clear();
                console.log('Geography=> '+data[0]);
                console.log('Customer Type=> '+data[2]);
            });

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" class="display" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>APAC</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>AMRevenue</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CAAP</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>CARevenue</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JAPA</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>JARevenue</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss some little thing, just check my code:

```
<table id="table" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

In file javascript:

```
    var dataSet = [
  [
    "Tiger Nixon",
    "System Architect",
    "Edinburgh",
    "5421",
    "2011/04/25",
    "$320,800"
  ]
];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#table").DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { title: "Name" },
      { title: "Position" },
      { title: "Office" },
      { title: "Extn." },
      { title: "Start date" },
      { title: "Salary" }
    ]
  });

  var table = $("#table").DataTable();

  $("#table tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
    var data = table.row().data();
    console.log('data', data);
    alert(data[0] + "'s salary is: " + data[5]);
  });
});
```

You will get your data in row